# Pandas- Create new columns by splitting cells on | n times

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with some survey results; each column is the response to a question. However, for a question that allowed multiple (<10) answers from checked boxes, the column has concatenated those answers with the format "Response 1 Checked | Response 4 Checked | Response 6 Checked ....", so I can't just split the column based on a predefined order, as it doesn't say when something was not checked.

```
ID     NormalResponse    MultipleCheckboxResponse
1      Answer3           Response 3
2      Answer1           Response 1| Response 7
3      Answer2           Response 2| Response 4| Response 7
4      Answer2           Response 2 | Response 3
```

How do I split these reasons out as new columns, preferably just with a boolean marker or 1/0 in the cell to determine if it was marked.

I'd like to see

```
ID     NormalResponse    Response1    Response2   Response3     Response4...
1      Answer3           0            0            1            0
2      Answer1           1            0            0            0
3      Answer2           0            1            0            1
4      Answer2           0            1            1            0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume you have a dataframe like this

```
df
#  ID NormalResponse       MultipleCheckboxResponse
#0  1        Answer3                      Response3
#1  2        Answer1            Response1|Response7
#2  3        Answer2  Response2|Response4|Response7
#3  4        Answer2            Response2|Response3
```

You can do the following

```
responses  = df.MultipleCheckboxResponse.unique() # find unique responses in each column
u_response = set( [ x for sublist in responses for x in sublist.split('|') ] ) # find total unique responses in dataframe (maps the 2d list responses to a 1d list)
#{'Response1', 'Response2', 'Response3', 'Response4', 'Response7'}
```

(Note that the set function returns only unique values). At this point you can iterate over the unique responses. For each response variable you should

1. create a data column matching response variable name
2. initializing each value for 0
3. Check each row if the column name (response variable) is in the `MultiCheckboxResponse` column. If it is, set the row val to 1.

this is what the loop should look like.

```
for col in u_response:
    df[col] = 0 # initialize the col
    df.loc[df.MultipleCheckboxResponse.str.contains(col), col] = 1 # adjust as necessary

df
#  ID NormalResponse       MultipleCheckboxResponse  Response7  Response4  \
#0  1        Answer3                      Response3          0          0   
#1  2        Answer1            Response1|Response7          1          0   
#2  3        Answer2  Response2|Response4|Response7          1          1   
#3  4        Answer2            Response2|Response3          0          0   

#   Response2  Response3  Response1  
#0          0          1          0  
#1          0          0          1  
#2          1          0          0  
#3          1          1          0
```

See [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html) for more ideas on working with text data.

### update

you seem to have extraneous white spaces, so you might want to change the `u_response` line of code to

```
u_response = set( [ x.strip() for sublist in responses for x in sublist.split('|') ]
```

where we added the `strip` method. This way your column titles do not have white spaces.

Comment: Thanks! As I can't update my version of pandas, this seems like the best solution for me. I was able to create all the new columns as you suggested. Unfortunately when I'm running through the loop, I get an error on the df.loc lookup "cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values." u_response is just a set of strings, no NA / NaN values, so I'm not sure why this is happening. Any ideas?

Comment: It seems that the Series ```df.MultipleCheckboxResponse.str.contains(col)``` (which is a boolean vector) somehow contains Na values. You should set the Na values to false, for instance ```df.MultipleCheckboxResponse.str.contains(col).fillna(False)```

Comment: You can also use ```df.MultipleCheckboxResponse.str.contains(col,na=False)``` which is preferable. Anyhow, [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html) is the reason you see the error, scroll to the bottom

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html), after some string manipulation to remove the spaces around the vertical bars `|`:

```
>>> resp = df.MultipleCheckboxResponse.str.replace("[\s]*\|[\s]*", "|")
>>> dummies = resp.str.get_dummies(sep="|")
>>> df.iloc[:,:2].join(dummies)
   ID NormalResponse  Response 1  Response 2  Response 3  Response 4  Response 7
0   1        Answer3           0           0           1           0           0
1   2        Answer1           1           0           0           0           1
2   3        Answer2           0           1           0           1           1
3   4        Answer2           0           1           1           0           0
```

Note though that this will only generate columns for the responses which were ever actually seen.  If you want a `response6` column even though no one ever reported response6, then you'll need to add those in a loop yourself.

Comment: the amount of functionality built into pandas never ceases to amaze me

Comment: Thanks! I'm getting "AttributeError: 'StringMethods' object has no attribute 'get_dummies'" . Not sure why that is, I'm doing the standard import pandas as pd and only changed out your code to reference my df and the fieldname. But clearly I'm being an idiot somewhere. Thoughts?

Comment: @John: most likely you're using an older version of pandas (I'm using 0.16.2).  What version are you using?

Comment: Hmm, can you do ```pandas.get_dummies``` ?

Answer (score 0):

Update: there is at least one answer above that is far better than mine. Don't waste your time with mine.

Pandas Series module has string manipulation functions which may come in handy here. Let's start by trying:

```
from pandas import Series

response_series = df['MultipleCheckboxResponse']
split_responses = response_series.str.split('|')
```

That will split up the concatenated responses. Each element in the returned series will be a list containing each response in that row. From here we can iterate over the length of the series, and the length of each list within the series, placing each individual response in a new column in the original dataframe.

```
for i in range(0, len(split_responses)):
    for j in range(0, len(split_responses.iloc[i]+1):
        df[j+4][i] = split_responses.iloc[i][j]
```